# Blender game: How can I make a ball roll while moving?

Tags: python, game-engine, objects, physics, logic-bricks

I'm making a game where a robotic ball moves, collects objects and passes obstacles, and my question is :

- how can I make the ball roll while it is moving ?

l'm familiar with how to make collectible game objects and with in game animation but l just don't known how to make a ball roll while moving. l understand how to program with the logic bricks.

Answer (score 3):

Torque causes rotational motion; therefore, applying torque will make the ball roll. This can be done with logic bricks or with python.

For both ways start out on the ball's physics, set *Physics Type* to *Ridge Body* and adjust the radius to the the size of the ball.
[image: Physics settings]

### Logic bricks

Then on the ball add a *Motion* actuator. On the motion actuator, uncheck *use local torque* (the *L* on the right) and set the torque on one of the axes.

[image: Motion actuator]

Connect keyboard sensors to the motion actuators with corresponding torque for the axis.

[image: Complete logic setup]

### Python

Using python, create a text block and add this script.

```
from bge import logic, events

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
keyboard = logic.keyboard.events

x, y = 0, 0

if keyboard[events.UPARROWKEY]: x += 1
if keyboard[events.DOWNARROWKEY]: x -= 1
if keyboard[events.LEFTARROWKEY]: y += 1
if keyboard[events.RIGHTARROWKEY]: y -= 1

cont.owner.applyTorque((x, y, 0))
```

Then connect an *Always* sensor to a *Python* controller and activate *TRUE level triggering.*
[image: Logic bricks for script]

**Result**
The logic bricks or script will roll the ball. **This is a monkey shaped ball.**
[image: Ball rolling around]

Comment: Is `applyTorque` only accessible via `bge`? I mean, is it possible to do anything `bge` can via `bpy`? I've started learning it, and it seems to me `bge` exposes other functionalities that I don't need for my animation.

Comment: `bpy` and `bge` are completely separate modules. The first is made for blender, the latter is only for the game engine. The functionality from `bge` is almost always reproducible in `bpy`. However there is plenty that is not accessible through `bge`.

Comment: Thank you! In this case, what would be the `bpy` equivalent to `applyTorque`? Actually, should I create another question about this?

Comment: @Yamaneko probably a good idea to make a new question. (I do not know off the top of my head).